# Angular 7 stylesheet in development configuration only

Tags: angular

I have a `src/styles/debug.scss` file to add some little helper styles for developers only, but these should not be shown in production.  What is the best way to include this stylesheet **only** when in development mode?

I have tried a few things inside `angular.json`, but no luck yet.

At the `root > projects > {project-name} > architect > build > configurations` level I assumed I could add the following

```
"development": {
  "styles": [
    "src/styles/debug.scss"
  ]
}
```

but this seems to do nothing.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're halfway there (assuming the goal is to work with `ng serve`).

What you have done is defined a `development` configuration that you can optionally include in the `ng build` command to include the debug styles in the build artifact.
You should be able to run this build using `ng build --configuration=development` and verify that it behaves as intended.

The next step is to define a `development` configuration for the `ng serve` command that will target the `development` build configuration.  Update `root > projects > {project-name} > architect -> serve` with the following (substituting in your {project-name}):

```
"development" {
  "browserTarget": "{project-name}:build:development"
}
```

Now, you should be able to run `ng serve --configuration=development` and have your debug styles included.

Comment: So that works... but it seem to **only** include this one file when in development mode.  Is there a way to make it include all the files defined in build > options> styles, or to I need to re-list these files here now?

Comment: Ahh I hadn't thought of that.  My understanding is that it is overriding the `styles` of the default build options, so you will have to re-list them.  There may be a better way, but not that I am aware of.